# Track opening rate of Outlook emails being sent through MS Access?

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, google-analytics

I send MS Outlook emails via MS Access.

Is there any way to check if the emails are being opened or is there a service I can link with this to track the analytics of the email?

```vb
‘Code to format email and set it to variable strHTML here

‘code to send email
With cdomsg
    .To = emailstr
    .FROM = fromemailstr
    .subject = Forms!frmMain.txtSubject
    .HTMLBody = strHTML
    .Send
End With
Set cdomsg = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

open rates are very hard to detect.  You have to use outside services to actually detect if your email was opened.  Your email will at least have to support html (not text only) to know if it was opened.  usually its a reference to in the body of an html email

```
 <img src="http://yourdomain.com/file.jpg?campainid=52&send_method=Access" height=0px;width=0px;">
```

JavaScript is usually out of the question in emails, but not as much in web mail.

It would be best to use a email tracking provider, then to reinvent this wheel yourself, but you can try with my idea.

There are many other methods out there using email tracking tools

Comment: The thing with email tracking provider is that they usually want you to send an email through that provider however in my case it is a little more difficult because I am trying to send emails as many different people. For example if I have a list of patients, and I want to send out emails with the corresponding signature so that it appears that they are receiving these emails from their specific doctor. From what I am aware of these email tracking providers don't go that complex. My Access application is coded to do such.

Comment: Then your going to have to do with what i have stated.  You will have to have a web server that does nothing but has code that captures all the paramaters that i listed after the ? and code them to insert this information back into your database.  As for open, the image tag should work (fyi outlook thats on auto preview might be false positives), also some newer outlook blocks images, but i think the GET is still made.